# Stack overflow error occurred when same data frame is repeated inside pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

When same dataframe is repeated inside loop then stack overflow error occurred.
Data volume is just 40k records. Cluster size is tried with single node 14Gb/28gb.

Sample data.

```
FT/RT,Country,Charge_Type,Tariff_Loc,Charge_No,Status,Validity_from,Validity_to,Range_Basis,Limited_Parties,Charge_Detail,Freetime_Unit,Freetime,Count_Holidays,Majeure,Start_Event,Same/Next_Day,Next_Day_if_AFTER,Availability_Date,Route_Group,Route_Code,Origin,LoadZone,FDischZone,PODZone,FDestZone,Equipment_Group,Equipment_Type,Range_From,Range_To,Cargo_Type,commodity,SC_Group,SC_Number,IMO,Shipper_Group,Cnee_Group,Direction,Service,haulage,Transport_Type,Option1,Option2,1st_of_Route_Group,1st_of_LoadZone,1st_of_FDischZone,1st_of_PODZone,1st_of_FDestZone,1st_of_Equipment_Group,1st_of_SC_Group,1st_of_Shipper_Group,1st_of_Cnee_Group,operationalFacilityGroup,operationalFacility,operator,commodityGroup,equipmentType,consignee,consigneeGroup,shipper,shipperGroup,serviceContract,serviceContractGroup,transportMode,agreementType
FT,IN,DET,INCCU,34298,EXPIRED,02-07-2020,30-11-2020,C/B,Y,2,DAY,14,Y,N,DISCHARG,S,null,N,MSL,null,null,null,null,null,null,ADRY,null,null,null,null,2313,null,ONLINE1,null,null,null,IMP,null,null,null,null,null,A1,null,null,null,null,20BULK,null,null,null,INCCU,,MSL,MSL,null,,null,,null,ONLINE1,null,null,SPOT
```

Expected output as below

[image]

Works for few records,if dataframe has mroe records stackoverflow error occured.

Please find the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The error is because of the usage of `DataFrame.withColumn()` inside a loop. This can cause performance issues and throw StackOverflow error according to this official documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html

Comment: Please give information about how your initial data looks like, your expected output data and reasons so that an alternate approach can be used.

Comment: Question is udpated, Reason is need to convert into JSON format for those dealkeys and dealcomponent keys. Ex.  [[{"keyname": "Direction", "value": "IMP", "description": ".."},.......so on]

Comment: Hey @JayaPrakash, can you please edit the question to post image as code.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs mainly because of the usage of `DataFrame.withColumn()`. Using this method multiple times/ inside loops can cause this error. Refer to this official documentation to understand about `DataFrame.withColumn()`.

[pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn — PySpark 3.3.0 documentation (apache.org)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html)

The only way to counter this error is to optimize the code. Since you want to convert the data of multiple columns to JSON data, you can try implementing the following code.

- Instead of using loops to add a new column that consists of JSON data, use `create_map()` function. This function converts multiple Pyspark columns into one `MapType()` column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.withColumn("dealKeys",create_map(   

        lit("Direction"),create_map(lit("Value"),col("Direction"),lit("Description"),lit("...")),   
        lit("Country"),create_map(lit("Value"),col("Country"),lit("Description"),lit("..."))
        ))
```

- The output will be as shown in the below image. I have created a `MapType()` with key as the column name and its value as a `MapType()`. This value consists of key value pairs of value of column and its description.

[image]

- Though this output is not same as your requirement, this transformation of data is much easier to access and perform further transformations even without using loops. You can use `df['dealKeys.Direction']` to get its value(MapType()) or you can use `df['dealKeys.Direction.Value']` to directly get the value it is holding.